# Symfony2 How to have access to a set of data in all controllers?

Tags: php, symfony

I have searched but I can't find any similar issues or maybe I am phrasing it wrong. What I want to achieve is access to an object in all the controllers in my Bundle. For example:

```
<?php

namespace Example\CoreBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class FolderController extends Controller
{

    function indexAction()
    {

         $title = $this->folder->getTitle();
         $description = $this->folder->getDescription();

    }

}
```

Usually outside of Symfony I would have extended the Controller class myself with BaseController extends Controller and set this up in the construct method but I know Symfony doesn't use the construct method so I am a bit stuck as to where to go.

I would usually do something like this:

```
class BaseController extends Controller
{

     function __construct()
     {

          parent::__construct();
          //load up the folder from my model with an ID
          $this->folder = $folder;

     }

}
```

I would then extend BaseController from FolderController and go from there but I have tried this with Symfony and it does not work. I have looked into Services but do not think this is what I need to make this work. If any more details are required please let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, services are indeed what you're looking for.

First, define a service in `services.yml`:

```
services:
    vendor.folder_manager:
        class: Vendor\FolderBundle\Entity\Manager\FolderManager
        arguments:
            em: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
            class: Vendor\FolderBundle\Entity\Folder
```

Then create that `FolderManager` class:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\FolderBundle\Entity\Manager;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class FolderManager
{
    protected $em;

    protected $repo;

    protected $class;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em, $class) {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->class = $class;
        $this->repo = $em->getRepository($class);
    }

    public function findById($id) {
        return $this->repo->findById($id);
    }

    public function getRepository() {
        return $this->repo;
    }
}
```

Finally, in your controller:

```
$this->container->get('vendor.folder_manager')->findById($folderId);
```

Or:

```
$this->container->get('vendor.folder_manager')->getRepository()->findById($folderId);
```

Symfony2 will automatically inject the entity manager the class into the manager, so all you have to provide in the controller is the folder's id.

**Edit:**
To make it prettier, you could also make a shortcut function in your controller:

```
protected function getFolderManager()
{
    return $this->container->get('vendor.folder_manager');
}
```

Then you can do:

```
$this->getFolderManager()->findById($folderId);
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response Pier-Luc! I was unsure if it was what I needed, I will give this a try and post feedback - do you know if there is a way to access the way I wanted though? instead of making the container get call in each method? or would I just need to do a construct in each controller and call this? will give it a shot and see - thanks!

Comment: Is there an advantage to using a service over just loading an entity in the controller and doing the find call with that?

Comment: No problem, services are a bit arcane until you "get it". You can make it prettier with a shortcut function, but that's the way to achieve what you're trying to do! As for your other comment, yes, services are reusable and thus DRYer

Comment: Ye it's a bit of a learning curve, not been too bad but just little things holding me up. I will have a search on the shortcut function bit too. thanks.

Comment: Should I create the service in vendor along with where twig, symfony all are? also will the php filename be FolderManager.php? thanks

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't! Assuming you have a FolderBundle, define it within the FolderBundle\Resources\config\services.yml
The file name has no real importance, it's just for readability.

Comment: so do I need to create a vendor folder in my bundle?

Comment: No, Vendor is just your bundle prefix, it can be anything. In AppKernel you probably have something like "new Vendor\FolderBundle\VendorFolderBundle()", replace Vendor with whatever you are using

Comment: right I get you now - just started making those changes - will update in a moment, thanks